# open graph protocol for google plus

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one, facebook-opengraph

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"
 xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.98quotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/mysis2-300x300.gif"/>
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.4.22 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
<title>sister love1 - 98Quotes</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.98quotes.com/sister-love1/" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="sister love1 - 98Quotes" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Search TagX on Google View all posts tagged as Tagx Find TagX related info in WikiPedia I love my sister Your sister isn’t always your blood relation. Sometimes it’s that close friends who understands you, loves you and has always got your back. If you have a loving sister or someone in your life you &hellip;" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.98quotes.com/sister-love1/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="98Quotes" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="I Love You" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Sister" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Relationship" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2013-11-07T12:20:10+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.98quotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/mysis2.gif" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="98Quotes"/>
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

my page head is as above.. but still google+ unable to fetch content, though it fetch the image. Can any body tell me what is the reason for it.

Comment: Please be more specific about what behaviour you are seeing and what behaviour you wish to be seeing. Currently G+ shows the image and title I would expect for your site.

Comment: Yes it's only show image and title of the page. If I want share some conten also then what I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The +Snippet description/preview is now only displayed on Google+ if you use [interactive shares](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive).

Comment: Does this also apply to an image tag? Also, in their docs, it doesn't say that description / preview is limited only to interactive shares. https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ Can you provide a reference for that. I couldn't find it searching for it.

Comment: Google+ is currently implementing a new share preview with larger image support. Those are showing the description again. Images have always worked assuming the markup is good. Someone on the Google+ Platform team said it in a comment in the Developing with G+ community.